# Failed to find JAVA_HOME Linux Mint: Trying to use Cordova to build an Android App

Tags: java, android, linux, cordova

I am trying to build an Android app with Cordova. Every time I run the command:

```
$ sudo cordova build android
```

it shows:

> Error: Failed to find 'JAVA_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.

My .bashrc is:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/eduarda/Android/Sdk
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.9.0-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin
```

More details:

```
$ which java
/usr/bin/java

$ java -version
openjdk version "9-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode)

$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.9.0-openjdk-amd64

$ echo $PATH

/home/eduarda/bin:/home/eduarda/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games://usr/lib/jvm/java-1.9.0-openjdk-amd64/bin
```

I don't know what to do, I think the error is with the java version, but I also don't know how to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo` is almost certainly clearing your environment. You need to set `JAVA_HOME` for `root` or for all users in, e.g, `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bashrc`.

Alternatively, you can run the command as your normal user. Is `sudo` really necessary for Cordova?

Comment: I typed
 
$ cordova build android

and got this

ANDROID_HOME=/home/eduarda/Android/Sdk
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.9.0-openjdk-amd64
Error: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater

Comment: It fixed one problem not having sudo, now I think I need to remove older versions of Java, thanks.

Comment: @EduardaBuss How did you fix your problem? If you did. My problem is so similar to yours. I'm just using Ionic.  Then I  type `sudo cordova requirements android --verbose` It can't see any variables.I did set them in `.bashrc` in  `/etc/profile` and in `/etc/bashrc`. But still, don't work.If I run a command without `sudo` i get a permission error.